# Vertical space on elements with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, positioning

How can I make elements with `position:absolute` and **dynamic height** occupy vertical space using only css? Is there any trick with containers and display that I can use?

Comment: `position: absolute` means they don't occupy space in the flow. Please post an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm animating a series of divs from right to left in js using positions, but the structure could by anything. I was wondering if maybe there was a not-so-legal trick to make it use vertical space (perhaps not)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, using absolute positioning means, by definition, that your element is no longer taking up space. So no, only through css there is no way to do this.

You can of course use jQuery (or plain javascript) to accomplish this. How I'd do it is have a `space` element next to each vertical element. Enclose both the space element and the absolutely positioned vertical element in a relatively positioned div. On page load, change the [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) of the space element to match the height of the vertical element.

Answer (score 4):

`position: absolute` means they don't occupy space in the flow. However, you don't have to animate using margin, you can use `float` to let the elements take up whatever space, and make each of the elements  `position:relative`.

```
div.animate-me {
   width: 300px;
   margin: 20px;
   float: left;
   left: -1000px; // Make them start offscreen
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
   visibility: hidden
}​

$('div').css().animate({
    left: 0
});
```

[**SAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxzzX/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/qxzzX/1/

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't apply to all situations, but: if the `position: absolute` element has a fixed aspect ratio (e.g. an image or video resizing responsively with `height: auto`), you can take advantage of the [`padding-bottom` trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to give a spacer element that same aspect ratio, so that it resizes in tandem with the `absolute` element:

```
.spacer {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 125%; /* for a 1.25 height/width ratio */
}
```

You can read the link, but this works because `padding-bottom` with a percentage is interpreted as a percentage of the element's width.

It's then up to your particular layout to position the spacer such that it precisely covers or underlays the `position: absolute` element, and takes up the space that your `absolute` element would have were it not `absolute`.

Comment: Wow, this batting trick is great. But I wonder if there is a way to use 100% of the height of the parent element insteam of its width