# How to set div height with relative position as child div with absolute position using css?

Tags: css-position

parent div height should be adjusted to child div height so that parent does not overlap each other. How to do that?

http://jsbin.com/zeluke/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Please post your original code, your issue in a screenshot possibly; External links are helpful but they may become invalid in future

Comment: Being taken out of flow, an absolute positioned child can't give content width/height to its parent. Could you tell why it need to be positioned absolute? ... and what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical space on elements with position:absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837401/vertical-space-on-elements-with-positionabsolute)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is being asked here, that is, parent and child height/width/position should not overlap? or as in the example, childs should be in separate positions?

First, Keep parent div with relative position and set its width/height. Here parent div without height/width are dimensionless, looking like overlapping.
Then, second, for childs with absolute position, have their height/width/(left,right,top,bottom) properties set. Position elements are used with (left,right,top,bottom) properties which have default values as auto, browser sets that and as you can it is same for both childs ie childs are in same position relative to their parents. These 2 steps will make child and parent being in their own places. You can also look into adding margin/padding for them for more separation in visuals.

Please remember, absolute position is position relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. Also, do consider using (left,right,top,bottom) properties.

Comment: If you are not sure what's asked, don't answer.